# Bouncing a specific email addresses incoming mail

Tags: email, gmail

I have a need to "bounce" email from a specific email address.  Meaning, when this person emails me I would like them to receive the MAILER_DAEMON message saying that the email address is no longer valid or some other "official looking" message that would make them believe that the email address (mine) is no longer valid.

Is it possible?  I have Gmail but I am also a programmer so I would not be afraid to get my hands dirty with some kind of "server" that takes forwarded emails and then re-routes them or anything creative like that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Apple used to include this feature in their mail app. There was a menu item
labeled "bounce" If you integrated into say, Thunderbird, you should be able to send the bounce. Alternatively, google has gmail API's that can read and send from your gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

A [Delivery Status Notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message) message is not hard to create on your own. You might have to tweak something to properly set an empty envelope sender (so as to produce an empty `Return-Path:`), but other than that, just write a reply with the desired text, and invoke it from your `.procmailrc` or whatever.

If you have direct access to the delivery machine, you might get away with just returning a particular error code, and the MTA will bounce the message for you, but the exit code depends on the MTA. Many implementations use Sendmail's conventions, but e.g. qmail has its own. http://www.eden.net.nz/7/20011101pairprocmail.html explains this from a Procmail perspective in some detail, and has the pertinent exit codes for both Sendmail-compatibles (which includes Postfix) and Qmail.

```
:0
* ^From: Annoying Perp <troll@example\.com>
{ EXITCODE=67 HOST= }  # Exit with Sendmail code for "no such user"
```

The Postfix document http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html explains the processing model in much more detail -- some of it is specific to Postfix, but as with all the Postfix documentation, it is understandable and helpful to the technically adept reader.

If you want to roll your own, your first stop would be [RFC 3464](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3464.txt); it's not a very tough read.

The [Postfix `bounce`(5) manual page](http://www.postfix.org/bounce.5.html) is very hands-on.

Comment: wow - that was a lot of jargon I am not familiar with.  I have never done any email related programming, however I think this may be enough to get me started with the research.  Thank you for the contribution.  Extra credit if you could tell me a good place to start looking?  Shall I just google "DSN tutorial"?  Is this something I can use Python's Twisted package for?  I've been looking for an excuse to try it out :P

Comment: Updated the answer.  I fail to see what Twisted could offer over a simple shell script, but I'm not particularly familiar with it, and I hear you can do pretty much anything with it.

Comment: You may want to think more about who your audience is. For me, the postfix bounce manpage is easier to read than your answer. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The question is very broad so I did not want to get into nitty-gritty details without more knowledge of the OP's environment and competences, but I guess there won't be any new information about that. I'll think about making my answer more concrete.

Comment: See also now http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274302/produce-bounce-message-when-sendmail-fails for a quick and dirty hands-on implementation sketch.